# Where are the screens for the Prestige class bassinet seats on Korean Air Boeing 777-300ER?

Tags: seating, korean-air

I've booked a Prestige class ticket (yay miles!) from Korea to the USA, and I'm considering my seats. I prefer window seats, so I'm considering [9J or 15A](https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Korean_Air/Korean_Air_Boeing_777-300ER.php). 9J is a bassinet seat, though. On the other seats, the VOD screen would be in the back of the seat in front. For the bassinet seats, is the screen on the wall or in the armrest?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per this [flyertalk post](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/27950710-post2.html)

> Since you're saying 9J is a bassinet seat, you're talking about Prestige Sleeper, not the newest product. I believe bulkhead seats have the screen coming out of the side armrest.
>
> The newest product (Prestige Suite on 748 and newer 77W, and 789) doesn't offer bassinet in J. Cruel, huh?

Edit: this has been confirmed by Korean Air on Facebook.

[image]

Comment: Have a link to the Facebook confirmation? Also, did you post this in flyertalk?

Comment: Yes I did. And there is no link sorry it was in a very brief message. I added a screenshot of it.